# Install Xamarin Mono for Android

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin

I am trying to install Xamarin's Mono for Android, Initially it said that for this I will need JDK, Android SDK, Mono Develop and then the most important package that will be downloaded and installed ie, The Mono for Android for Visual Studio and Mono Develop...

So I tried a manual install :

I had JDK.
I downloaded Monodevelop and its pre-requisites..
I downloaded thew Android SDK revision 20 for Windows7, and then for installing the Android AVD and SDK completely I installed SDK Platform tools, Google USB Driver, System Image(only for API 14) and SDK Platform 14..

Now I tried Xamarin and it says That Android SDK is not installed and will be downloaded and installed..So I looked at the logs and downloaded the SDK Platforms 7,8,10,12

Now can u plzz tell that after installing all the below sdk platforms manually??

android-7 ("Android SDK Platform 2.1_r3")
android-8 ("Android SDK Platform 2.2_r3")
android-10 ("Android SDK Platform 2.3.3._r2")
android-12 ("Android SDK Platform 3.1, revision 3")
android-14 ("Android SDK Platform 4.0")

I just want Xamarin to detect that I have Android SDK installed.

**Will I have to install the system images of these versions for Xamarin to detect Android SDK??** I only have the system image of API 14.

Comment: So long has passed, and Mono for Android becomes Xamarin.Android, and less and less people use Visual Studio 2010. Thus, I think we should close this question as cannot reproduce.

Comment: ok, I think you are right. How do i do that? When I tried to close the question by clicking the "delete" button , it dint allow me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many bug reports already on Xamarin's tracker regarding the installers, such as

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=859

So you should report new ones if you cannot find an existing item that matches the problem you met.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, I've had much better luck relying on Xamarin's automatic install process.  They've been pretty thorough about detecting (and automatically downloading) all the needed components.  Did you have a chance to review their documentation - [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/installation/Installation_for_Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Xamarin's Mono for Android in Visual Studio and want to Visual Studio detect your android sdk, go to

> Visual Studio -> Tools -> Xamarin -> Android Settings

and set **Android SDk Location**